# c++ array within structure

Tags: c++, arrays, class, structure

Im making a program that will find the area of a polygon. The number of vertices changes. I created a structure that used an array containing the points. heres the code for that part:

```
public:

int vertices;
struct triangleStruct{

  int verts[vertices][vertices];
};
```

This gives an error "invalid use of non static data member Triangle::verticies" This is within a class called triangle. Why?!?!

Comment: `struct`s must have a size fixed at compile time.

Comment: let me explain more: the class construct is triangle (int) and it sets the number of vertices. the function that does this sets the value imputed to the vertices variable.

Comment: But for that data structure the compiler needs to be given a fixed size. You need dynamic allocation for what you want to do. Maybe look at `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1):

To declare an array, specifies the type of the elements and the number of elements required by an array as follows:

```
type arrayName [ rows][ cols ];
```

The `rows` and `cols` must be an integer constant greater than zero.
In short size of array should be available at compile time, but in your case you are trying to provide dynamic size to allocate array that's why this error is occuring. For this I would suggest use [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).